# Is there a way to unit test a function with static variables?

Tags: php, unit-testing, reflection, phpunit

Ιs there a way to test a function containing static variables using [PHPUnit](https://phpunit.de/)?

For example,

```php
class MyClass {
  public function my_method() {
    static $already_invoked = false;
    
    if ($already_invoked) {
      return;
    }

    echo 'Hello world';

    $already_invoked = true;
  }
}
```

`my_method()` will print `Hello world` exactly one time, no matter how many times it's called.

```php
$instance = new MyClass();
$instance->my_method();
$instance->my_method();
```

outputs:

```
Hello world
```

Having just one test

```php
<?php
class MyMethodTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
    public function test_should_print_hello_world_exactly_one_time() {
        $instance = new MyClass();
        $instance->my_method();
        $instance->my_method();

        $this->expectOutputString('Hello world');
    }
}
```

passes:

```
MyMethod
 ✔ Should print hello world exactly one time
```

However, adding another test

```php
<?php
class MyMethodTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
    public function test_should_print_hello_world() {
        (new MyClass())->my_method();

        $this->expectOutputString('Hello world');
    }

    public function test_should_print_hello_world_exactly_one_time() {
        $instance = new MyClass();
        $instance->my_method();
        $instance->my_method();

        $this->expectOutputString('Hello world');
    }
}
```

causes the previously passing test to fail, because of the `static` variable:

```
MyMethod
 ✔ Should print hello world
 ✘ Should print hello world exactly one time
   │
   │ Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
   │ --- Expected
   │ +++ Actual
   │ @@ @@
   │ -'Hello world'
   │ +''
   │
```

Now, I know I could use a static **property** instead:

```php
class MyClass {
    private static bool $already_invoked = false;

    public function my_method() {
        if (self::$already_invoked) {
            return;
        }

        echo 'Hello world';

        self::$already_invoked = true;
    }
}
```

That way, I could use a reflection property to reset its value immediately after each test, like this:

```php
class MyMethodTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {
    // ...

    public function tearDown() {
        $ref = new ReflectionProperty('MyClass', 'already_invoked');
        $ref->setAccessible(true);
        $ref->setValue(null, false);
    }
}
```

And then, both tests pass:

```
MyMethod
 ✔ Should print hello world
 ✔ Should print hello world exactly one time
```

In my case, though, I'm dealing with legacy code and I'd like to write some unit tests *before* refactoring it.

I've also tried to run each test in isolation (although that's not ideal since it'd probably end up being considerably slower) using the [`@runInSeparateProcess`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/annotations.html#runinseparateprocess) method annotation, but that seems to be failing because the process isolation feature requires serialization:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'ReflectionClass' is not allowed in phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/GlobalState.php:151
```

Is there a way to test a function containing `static` variables?

Comment: `@runInSeparateProcess` is most likely the only way to sidestep your problem without changing the existing code. Maybe you can disable `@preserveGlobalState` to get rid of the mentioned error.

Comment: I had this problem once, and the simple solution was that I was poorly programming (if you need a static variable (public) that you depend on). I have 7+ years experience and I have nearly never needed a static variable, even with complex stuff... But the short answer is you can't (at least the normal way). So I recommend you that you change your approach and try to remove static variables as much as possible. There is no problem with `self` or `static`, but try to limit it use the more you can.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I totally agree with you. In my case, I'm dealing with legacy code, which I'm slowly refactoring. I just want to write some unit tests before modifying the code too much.

Comment: @over-engineer oohhh, that is awesome to hear ! First have test to then be able to refactor ! Awesome !